# Error when making a build of Ionic project : failed because of Groovy?

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework

I'd like to build my first project with Ionic, but I can't build it.
I've waiting while 7 minutes without a good result, althought I receive this log. I think that *Graddle* is well installed, but one of the following command failed.
My simple command line invocation is :

> Ionic build Android

I didn't find any info about mysterious **commitId**, could it be a unexpected reaction of the *Groovy* compilation ?

My received log is :

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-rc-1-bin.zip
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
............................................................................................

............................
....................................................................
Unzipping C:\Users\Gardien\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.12-rc-1-bin

\48ppqowafhejjlu04q14w3fma\gradle-2.12-rc-1-bin.zip
 to C:\Users\Gardien\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.12-rc-1-bin\48ppqowafhejjlu04q14w3fma
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/14.0.1/guava-jdk5-

14.0.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/google/guava/guava-parent-

jdk5/14.0.1/guava-parent-jdk5-14.0.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-

2.6.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/17/commons-

parent-17.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.1.0/pegdown-1.1.0.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.6.3/jsoup-1.6.3.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/googlecode/jarjar/jarjar/1.3/jarjar-1.3.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.0.2/parboiled-

core-1.0.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.0.2/parboiled-

java-1.0.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-parent/3.3.1/asm-parent-3.3.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-util/3.3.1/asm-util-3.3.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-analysis/3.3.1/asm-analysis-3.3.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/14.0.1/guava-jdk5-

14.0.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-

2.6.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.1.0/pegdown-1.1.0.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.6.3/jsoup-1.6.3.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/googlecode/jarjar/jarjar/1.3/jarjar-1.3.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.0.2/parboiled-

core-1.0.2.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.0.2/parboiled-

java-1.0.2.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-util/3.3.1/asm-util-3.3.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/asm/asm-analysis/3.3.1/asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar
:buildSrc:clean UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy
:buildSrc:processResources
:buildSrc:classes
:buildSrc:jar
:buildSrc:assemble
:buildSrc:checkstyleMain
Download 

https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/5.9/checkstyle-5.9.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-

core/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3
.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-

parent-11.pom
Download 

https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/5.9/checkstyle-5.9.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-

core/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3
.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.0-groovy-

2.4/spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/objenesis/objenesis-parent/1.2/objenesis-

parent-1.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.0-groovy-

2.4/spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar
:buildSrc:processTestResources
:buildSrc:testClasses
:buildSrc:checkstyleTest UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:codenarcMain
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/codenarc/CodeNarc/0.24.1/CodeNarc-

0.24.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/groovy-

all-2.4.4.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/gmetrics/GMetrics/0.7/GMetrics-0.7.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/codenarc/CodeNarc/0.24.1/CodeNarc-

0.24.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/groovy-

all-2.4.4.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/gmetrics/GMetrics/0.7/GMetrics-0.7.jar
:buildSrc:codenarcTest
:buildSrc:test
:buildSrc:check
:buildSrc:build
Downloading the released versions from: https://services.gradle.org/versions/all
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/uwyn/jhighlight/1.0/jhighlight-1.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/uwyn/jhighlight/1.0/jhighlight-1.0.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/24/commons-

parent-24.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.10/slf4j-parent-

1.7.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.7/jna-3.2.7.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-

platform/0.10/native-platform-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.2.1/jansi-

1.2.1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/guava-jdk5-

17.0.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/google/guava/guava-parent-jdk5/17.0/guava-

parent-jdk5-17.0.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-

annotations-1.0.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.20/kryo-

2.20.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-osx-

i386/0.10/native-platform-osx-i386-0
.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-osx-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-osx-amd64
-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-linux-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-linux-a
md64-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-linux-

i386/0.10/native-platform-linux-i3
86-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-windows-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-windo
ws-amd64-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-windows-

i386/0.10/native-platform-window
s-i386-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-freebsd-

i386/0.10/native-platform-freebs
d-i386-0.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-freebsd-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-freeb
sd-amd64-0.10.pom
Download 

https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/reflectasm/1.07/reflecta

sm-1.07.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-

1.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.3/asm-all-5.0.3.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.3/asm-parent-

5.0.3.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.7/jna-3.2.7.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-

platform/0.10/native-platform-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.2.1/jansi-

1.2.1.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/guava-jdk5-

17.0.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-

annotations-1.0.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.20/kryo-

2.20.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-osx-

i386/0.10/native-platform-osx-i386-0
.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-osx-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-osx-amd64
-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-linux-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-linux-a
md64-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-linux-

i386/0.10/native-platform-linux-i3
86-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-windows-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-windo
ws-amd64-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-windows-

i386/0.10/native-platform-window
s-i386-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-freebsd-

i386/0.10/native-platform-freebs
d-i386-0.10.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/net/rubygrapefruit/native-platform-freebsd-

amd64/0.10/native-platform-freeb
sd-amd64-0.10.jar
Download 

https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/reflectasm/1.07/reflecta

sm-1.07-shaded.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-

1.2.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.3/asm-all-5.0.3.jar
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/docbook/docbook-xsl/1.75.2/docbook-xsl-

1.75.2.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/docbook/docbook-xsl/1.75.2/docbook-xsl-

1.75.2.zip
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:announce:classpathManifest
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/ant/ant/1.9.6/ant-1.9.6.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.9.6/ant-parent-

1.9.6.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/commons-collections/commons-

collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.pom

Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/39/commons-

parent-39.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.10/jul-to-slf4j-

1.7.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.10/log4j-over-

slf4j-1.7.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.10/jcl-over-

slf4j-1.7.10.pom
Download https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.9.6/ant-

launcher-1.9.6.pom
:baseServices:classpathManifest
:baseServices:compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:baseServices:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:baseServices:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:baseServices:classes
:baseServices:jar
:baseServicesGroovy:classpathManifest
:baseServicesGroovy:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:baseServicesGroovy:compileGroovy
Note: C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper\subprojects\base-services-

groovy\src\main\groovy\org\gradle\
api\specs\AndSpec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:baseServicesGroovy:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:baseServicesGroovy:classes
:baseServicesGroovy:jar
:cli:classpathManifest
:cli:compileJava
:cli:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:cli:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:cli:classes
:cli:jar
:determineCommitId FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper\gradle\buildReceipt.gradle' 

line: 103

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':determineCommitId'.
> Could not determine commit id

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 

get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7 mins 50.583 secs
```

Comment: So it looks like it's trying to get the commit id for your git based project (I'm guessing to stick in a version string somewhere) try running `git init` in the main folder to see if that works?

Comment: Btw, this is a gradle thing, not a groovy thing so I switched tags

Comment: `git init` have reborn my files Head, decription and others. So it work ! Thanks.